# This password does not use the Bcrypt algorithm on laravel 10

Tags: laravel

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    // Validate the request
    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    // Attempt to find the user by username
    $user = User::where('username', $request->username)->first();

    // Check if the user exists
    if (!$user) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid credentials'], 401);
    }

    // Check if the password is correct
    if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        // Authentication successful, login the user
        Auth::login($user);

        // Redirect to the desired route
        return redirect()->intended('/');
    }

    // Authentication failed, return an error response
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid credentials'], 401);
}
```

this is the code that i use

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbOzg.png) this the data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA75W.png) i try to login then[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8zs5.png) this happen help me pls

i try ask all code ai but still cant solve the problems im newbie btw

Comment: Your password is in plaintext. I don't know if you just entered the password into the database or saved/created it with Laravel, but it needs to be stored after running the password through [`Hash::make()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/hashing#hashing-passwords)

Comment: It looks like you're storing your `password` values in plain text... You should be hashing these (which Laravel can do via `Hash::make()`).

Comment: use php artisan tinker, and type `Hash::make('andra')` to manually hash a password for testing purposes, and then you put the resulting string, `$2y$12$wUekVLhC0JmD9tHKAkz.PeoPCv4SqXba0kzQE80ja9UTFNxqP4Zfu` in your password field. You need to also do the same when you are registering an new user in database

Comment: Don't use "AI" generated code in general, and please don't come here asking for help with it, without having a basic understanding of what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... is there a reason you are basically rewriting what `Auth::attempt()` already does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, your hash checks are failing because you're storing the passwords in plaintext. This is absolutely *not* the way to do it.

If you're using Laravel's default User model, it should cast passwords to a hash when you create a user. Normally, your User model would look like this:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   ...

      protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];
}
```

This would allow you to create users as simply as:

```
$user = new User();
$user->username = 'hello@world.test';
$user->password = 'supersecretpassword';
$user->save();
```

With the password hashed in your DB, you can use Laravel's Auth helper to authenticate your users:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    // Validate the request
    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
         $request->session()->regenerate();
 
         return redirect()->intended('/');
     }

    // Authentication failed, return an error response
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid credentials'], 401);
}
```

Laravel auth docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Answer (score 2):

This error can also occur if the password field is null. For instance if you have implemented multiple sign in options a user who signed in initially with say Google will get this error if they try to login with email and password.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the verification of the hash you use for encryption not being the same as the Laravel system. If you use a special type of encryption in Laravel, look at the file `app\config\hashing.php` within your application, there you can configure if you want verification by bcrypt and change the hasing information in addition to `app\config\app.php`. for more information access [laravel hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/hashing)